# how to handle garbage value while making my own vector in c++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

Good evening guys
I am trying to make my own vector class.
But I have few problems.
Firstable, I dont know why There is garbage value
I've tried to check constructor but I couldn't find reason.

For example If i tried to make

```
Vector<int> arr1(5);

Vector<int> ::iterator it;
arr1.push_front(1);
arr1.push_back(2);
arr1.push_back(3);
arr1.push_back(4);
arr1.push_back(5);

for (it = arr1.begin(); it != arr1.end(); it++)
    cout << *it;
```

the result is
[1-842150451-842150451-842150451-842150451-8421504512345](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unfH1.png)

Second, I want to make Insert(firstPostion,secondPosition)
But I dont know how to make.
Plz help me Thanks.
I added my vector.h and main.cpp

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dsexceptions.h"

template <typename Object>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector(int initSize = 0)
        : theSize( initSize ), theCapacity( initSize + SPARE_CAPACITY )
    { objects = new Object[theCapacity]; }

    Vector(const Vector& rhs)
        : theSize(rhs.theSize), theCapacity( rhs.theCapacity ), objects( nullptr)
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            objects[k] = rhs.objects[k];
    }

    Vector& operator= (const Vector& rhs)
    {
        Vector copy = rhs;
        std::swap(*this, copy);
        return *this;
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] objects;
    }

    Vector(Vector&& rhs)
        : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ rhs.objects }
    {
        rhs.objects = nullptr;
        rhs.theSize = 0;
        rhs.theCapacity = 0;
    }

    Vector& operator= (Vector&& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(theSize, rhs.theSize);
        std::swap(theCapacity, rhs.theCapacity);
        std::swap(objects, rhs.objects);

        return *this;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return theSize;
    }
    int capacity() const
    {
        return theCapacity;
    }

    Object& operator[](int index)
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{ };
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    const Object& operator[](int index) const
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{ };
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    void resize(int newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > theCapacity)
            reserve(newSize * 2);
        theSize = newSize;
    }

    void reserve(int newCapacity)
    {
        if (newCapacity < theSize)
            return;

        Object* newArray = new Object[newCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            newArray[k] = std::move(objects[k]);

        theCapacity = newCapacity;
        std::swap(objects, newArray);
        delete[] newArray;
    }

    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(const Object& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = x;
    }
    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(Object&& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = std::move(x);
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        --theSize;
    }

    const Object& back() const
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        return objects[theSize - 1];
    }

    // Iterator stuff: not bounds checked
    typedef Object* iterator;
    typedef const Object* const_iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }

    static const int SPARE_CAPACITY = 2;

    /*************************************************************************/
    /*************************************************************************/

    iterator insert(const_iterator position, const Object& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize - 1; i >= index; --i)
            objects[i + 1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = val;
        theSize++;

        return &objects;
        
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator position, Object&& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize-1; i>=index; --i)
            objects[i+1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = std::move(val);
        theSize++;

        return objects;
    }

    
    template <class InputIterator>
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        
        
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        Object* newObjects = last - first;
        


        

        return &objects;
    }

    
    iterator erase(const_iterator position)
    {
        theSize--;
        int index = position - begin();
        
        Object* newObj = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= theSize; ++j)
        {
            if (j != index)
                newObj[i++] = objects[j];
        }
        delete[] objects;

        objects = newObj;
        

        return &objects[index];
    }

    
    iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
    {
        int index = last - first;
        theSize = index;
        Object* Array = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            Array[i] = objects[i + index];

        return Array;
    }


    
    void push_front(const Object& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[0] = val;
        theSize++;
    }

    void push_front(Object&& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[0] = std::move(val);
        theSize++;
        
    }

    
    Object& front()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{};
        return objects[0];
        
    }

    const Object& front() const
    {
        if (empty())
            throw UnderflowException{ };
        return objects[0];
    }

    /*************************************************************************/
    /*************************************************************************/



  private:
    int theSize;
    int theCapacity;
    Object * objects;
};

#endif


#include "Vector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Vector<int> arr1(5);
    Vector<int> arr2(5);
    Vector<int> ::iterator it;
    arr1.push_front(1);
    arr1.push_back(2);
    arr1.push_back(3);
    arr1.push_back(4);
    arr1.push_back(5);
    arr1.erase(arr1.begin(), arr1.begin() + 2);
    for (it = arr1.begin(); it != arr1.end(); it++)
        cout << *it;
    cout << endl;
    cout << arr1.size();
    
    
    
       

  


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. It will make it easier for us to understand what's happening, as well as for yourself to debug the code.

Comment: "I want to make Insert(firstPostion,secondPosition) " What is hard about it? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Why is your push_front excepting an argument as a reference?

Comment: @Yunnosch I've tried a couple of methods, but they all don't work, so I don't know how to approach them

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is the intended functionality? What is the specification of desired behaviour?

Comment: First you create a vector with five indeterminate values. then you add five more elements; 1 at the front and 2 3 4 5 at the back. (If you did this same thing with `std::vector`, you would see `1000002345`

Comment: @kiner_shah I don't get it. push_front is adding value in the first place. We need value to add.

Comment: @Yunnosch if i use insert(firstposition,secondpostion) for example arr1={1,2,3,4,5} arr2(arr1.begin(),arr1.begin()+2)  arr2={1,2}

Comment: ... then what happens? And what is supposed to happen? Can you pleae describe what that call or function is supposed to do? What is the intended effect of doing `insert(firstposition,secondpostion)` ?

Comment: Your `push_front` function doesn't add a new element to the front. It *replaces* the current front value. And increase the size even though no new element were added.

Comment: @Basicthings, you are passing an argument by reference to push_front. I was saying shouldn't it be by value? Also, do note that std::vector doesn't have push_front. push_front should have the effect of shifting all the elements to right and then inserting one element at the front.

Comment: As part of your problem (and as mentioned by @molbdnilo) when you create the vector with five elements, you allocate space for the five (plus some extra capacity?) elements but you don't initialize them. All the elements will have *indeterminate* values (look at them as garbage). Using such indeterminate data in any way, even printing them, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude True. I'm gonna fix the push_front function.

Comment: OT: Note that your vector does not behave as a standard vector. For instance, you construct new elements in `reserve`, which should not happen.

Comment: @Yunnosch The purpose is to add values . If i used insert(firstPosition,secondpostion) I can add values between first and second positions a={1,2,3,4,5} b ={10} b.insert(1,3) b={10 2 3}

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes I know they don't have puhs_front Thanks.

Comment: Please explain the number example you gave. How does each value in the result come to be there? Where does it come from? What do the parameter values mean? Maybe, instead of giving one example, you could describe what that operation is supposed to be doing. Have a look at [ask] for a description of how much effort you need to spend in order to overcome the problem that user users do not see your targert specification, do not see the rest of your project, cannot talk to the person who set your assignment and generally cannot read your mind.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks!! I think i get a clue.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks A lot !! But I don't get it. i made new elements but as you can see i swap it and delete it.

Comment: @Yunnosch Okay. I want to add Values firstposition <= values < secondposition if i do arr1.push_back(1) arr1.push_back(2) arr1.push_back(3) arr1.push_back(4)   arr1={1,2,3,4}     .I might want to copy "some" of the values of arr1. If i used arr2.insert(arr1.begin()(=arr1[0]),arr1.begin()+2(=arr1[0]+2 which is arr1[2]) ) the result is arr2 = {1,2}.

Comment: The description is "I want to add Values firstposition <= values < secondposition" the rest is example again. And are you sure that you want to insert based on a relation between what seems to be meant as an index and a some values? Which values?

Comment: I might seem nagging, sorry for that. What I am trying to illustrate is that if you do not have a decent definition of what you are supposed to implement you will be hard pressed to come up with an implementation. Which is exactly what you describe. So please, spend some time on defining, in English, what the functionality you want to implement actually is. What should be affected? An instance of your own container? Which part of it should be affected? Existing entries? Newly to be inserted entries? Where are the values (for new entries, or for overwriting existing entries) come from?

Comment: From something global? From something referenced by parameters? You need to know these things, otherwise the lack of knowledge will get you as stuck as you now feel. Have a look at existing specifications (e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf ) can you describe your goal in that detail level? If not, you need to first decide what you actually want, or ask whoever gave you the assignment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude First, Thanks!! I think I understand what you want to say.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for helping me! As you said, I will try to define it clearly first.

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried to check https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ and That is what i want to make. It's exactly the same. I just want to make that function. 3rd one, range(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many misunderstanding.

Your range insert and erase is more than strange. There are some other bugs.

Please not, if you work with ranges in C++, then the end() of the range always has to point to one past the last element in the range.

Please the the comments that I put in your code.
I also replace all exceptions with std::exceptions so that I can compile.

Regarding the indeterminate values that you see.

If you create an Vector having the size 5, then these 5 values are initially indeterminate. Maybe you want to "reserve" 5 bytes?

But now you have the 5 bytes. And if you use `push_back` then the new values will be added after the 5 initial elements. As element index 5,6,7,8 and so on.

Please read about the API from `std::vector` in CPP Reference.

Please see your annotated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename Object>
class Vector
{
public:
    explicit Vector(int initSize = 0)                             
        : theSize(initSize), theCapacity(initSize + SPARE_CAPACITY)
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
    }

    Vector(const Vector& rhs)
        : theSize(rhs.theSize), theCapacity(rhs.theCapacity), objects(nullptr)
    {
        objects = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            objects[k] = rhs.objects[k];
    }

    Vector& operator= (const Vector& rhs)
    {
        Vector copy = rhs;          // Bug! Self Calling
        std::swap(*this, copy);     // Bug: Do not swap, you want to assign and both sould contain the same values
        return *this;
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] objects;
    }

    Vector(Vector&& rhs)
        : theSize{ rhs.theSize }, theCapacity{ rhs.theCapacity }, objects{ rhs.objects }
    {
        rhs.objects = nullptr;      // If this contains elements, then delete them
        rhs.theSize = 0;
        rhs.theCapacity = 0;
    }

    Vector& operator= (Vector&& rhs)
    {
                                                    // Delete old contents of this
        std::swap(theSize, rhs.theSize);            // Do not swap!!!  Move, like in the move assignment operator
        std::swap(theCapacity, rhs.theCapacity);
        std::swap(objects, rhs.objects);

        return *this;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return theSize;
    }
    int capacity() const
    {
        return theCapacity;
    }

    Object& operator[](int index)
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw std::out_of_range;
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    const Object& operator[](int index) const
    {
#ifndef NO_CHECK
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
            throw std::out_of_range;
#endif
        return objects[index];
    }

    void resize(int newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > theCapacity)  // Bug: Should be >=
            reserve(newSize * 2);
        theSize = newSize;
    }

    void reserve(int newCapacity)
    {
        if (newCapacity < theSize)
            return;

        Object* newArray = new Object[newCapacity];
        for (int k = 0; k < theSize; ++k)
            newArray[k] = std::move(objects[k]);

        theCapacity = newCapacity;
        std::swap(objects, newArray);  // Will work, but why always swapping? Assignment is sufficient
        delete[] newArray;
    }

    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(const Object& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)       // Just for safety: Should be >=
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1); // 2* the capacity should always be sufficient
        objects[theSize++] = x;
    }
    // Stacky stuff
    void push_back(Object&& x)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[theSize++] = std::move(x);
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::underflow_error;
        --theSize;
    }

    const Object& back() const
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::underflow_error;
        return objects[theSize - 1];
    }

    // Iterator stuff: not bounds checked
    typedef Object* iterator;
    typedef const Object* const_iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return &objects[0];
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return &objects[size()];
    }

    static const int SPARE_CAPACITY = 2;

    /*************************************************************************/
    /*************************************************************************/

    iterator insert(const_iterator position, const Object& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }

        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize - 1; i >= index; --i)
            objects[i + 1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = val;

        theSize++;

        return &objects;

    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator position, Object&& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        int index = position - objects;
        for (int i = theSize - 1; i >= index; --i)
            objects[i + 1] = objects[i];
        objects[index] = std::move(val);
        theSize++;

        return objects;
    }


    template <class InputIterator>
    iterator insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)         // Bug, completely wrong. Now insertion
        {
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        }
        Object* newObjects = last - first;  

        return &objects;
    }


    iterator erase(const_iterator position)
    {
        theSize--;
        int index = position - begin();     

        Object* newObj = new Object[theCapacity];       // Strange algorithm. Why copy all data instead of shifting
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= theSize; ++j)
        {
            if (j != index)
                newObj[i++] = objects[j];
        }
        delete[] objects;

        objects = newObj;


        return &objects[index];
    }


    iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
    {
        int index = last - first;
        theSize = index;            // Wrong and too comlicated
        Object* Array = new Object[theCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)     // Wrong
            Array[i] = objects[i + index];   // 

        return Array;
    }

    void push_front(const Object& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[0] = val;       // Bug. Just overwriting. No push front
        theSize++;              // No last value will be indeterminate
    }

    void push_front(Object&& val)
    {
        if (theSize == theCapacity)     // Bug. See above
            reserve(2 * theCapacity + 1);
        objects[0] = std::move(val);
        theSize++;

    }

    Object& front()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::underflow_error;
        return objects[0];

    }

    const Object& front() const
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::underflow_error;
        return objects[0];
    }
    /*************************************************************************/
    /*************************************************************************/
private:
    int theSize;
    int theCapacity;
    Object* objects;
};

int main()
{
    Vector<int> arr1(5);            // Creating a vector arr1 with 5 indeterminate elements
    Vector<int> arr2(5);            // Creating a vector arr1 with 5 indeterminate elements
    Vector<int> ::iterator it;
    arr1.push_front(1);             // Will set aissign one to the first element
    arr1.push_back(2);              // Will add a new element at the end. So, now first element has value, 2nd,3rd, 4th and 5th are indeterminate. Last will be 2
    arr1.push_back(3);              // See above
    arr1.push_back(4);              // See above
    arr1.push_back(5);              // See above
    arr1.erase(arr1.begin(), arr1.begin() + 2);         // Does not work correctly
    for (it = arr1.begin(); it != arr1.end(); it++)     // Will just show 2 values
        std::cout << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << arr1.size();
    return 0;
}
```